# Empty and Null Check with mapstruct

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mapstruct

I am trying to set mapping from `Student` to `StudentDTO`, both classes has "name" property.
I want to check `name` property of the source(`Student`) is not null and not empty then only map to the name of the target(`StudentDTO`)

Till now I have tried with `NullValueMappingStrategy`, `NullValueCheckStrategy` and `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy`,
but these just check null condition only.

How to check property for null and empty?

Comment: See if [this comment](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/879#issuecomment-244207990) helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by MapStruct. In the upcoming 1.5 release we are going to have possibility to write custom presence check methods that would check if the property is "present" and then perform the mapping.